# How to add Jquery Validation to Custom form and set error to field?

Tags: 8, forms

I want to implement client side validation using jQuery on my custom form.

I have enabled clientside validation contributed module

I have successfully attached custom js file using following code:

```
 $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'custom_form/cl-validation';
```

And in the JS file I have written below code:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.custom_form = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

        var selectedCountry = ''

        $("#country").change(function(){
          selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

        });


        $('#user-number-value').keyup(function(){   
              $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/(\d{2})|([a-z]{2})\-?/,'$1-'))
        });

         $("input#user-number-value").focus(function() { 
            if(selectedCountry == undefined || selectedCountry == '') {
                $('#user-number-value').va('')
               // I want mark country dropdown as red and show a error
            }
        });


    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

I am not getting how to do this using jquery and stop form submission.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If the form field is empty you need to stop propagation of the parent form. This should be what you need.

```
 countryValidation = function() {
    // Lets use a function so we can check the field
    $country = $('#country');
    if ($country.val() === '') {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  $('#user-number-value').on('focus', function(){
    if(countryValidation() === false){
      // If the field check comes back false on focus lets add a class
      $('#country').addClass('invalid');
    };   
  });

  $('#country').on('change', function(){
    // This will remove the class when the user fixes the error
    if(countryValidation() === true) {
      $('#country').removeClass('invalid'); 
    } else {
      $('#country').addClass('invalid');
    }   
  });

  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if(countryValidation() === false){
      // when the field comes back invalid lets add the class
      $('#country').addClass('invalid');
      // this will prevent the form from submitting
      e.preventDefault();
    }; 
  });
```

Comment: How would you display a message to that? please

Comment: @AlexSeif You can use the invalid/valid class to toggle a message if you wanted.

Comment: ty, it was kind of a challenge, coz I also had the pattern attribute, so it overrides my validation result, depending on which is triggered first. I ended up with server side validation. But I wanted to display a unique message for a unique scenario